# find the numerical value exist in the Expression C#

Tags: c#, string

How do I find:

`string str="(120)(1500)x";`

How to find out in the event that the string contains:

`string str1="()()X";`

I then have to print:

`console.writeline("str1 doesnt contain a numerical");`

Comment: Could you please rephrase that?

Comment: i think he needs to find whether there exists any number in a string. If No, print "str1 doesnt contain a numerical"

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = "asdfasfas";
if (!Regex.IsMatch(input, "[0-9]"))
{
    // will occure
}
else
{
    // will not occure
}

var input2 = "asdf123Aasdfasdf";
if (!Regex.IsMatch(input2, "[0-9]"))
{
    // will not occure
}
else
{
    // will occure
}
```

but remember: this will only check, if there are any digits, not that the string is easily convertable to a number!

more about [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch.aspx)

Comment: glad to hear that! if you found a solution, you might mark that answer properly :)

Comment: He's learning to use SO I guess, here's a +1 from me anyway :p

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you need (wich is quite unclear) with [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28VS.71%29.aspx) ([Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regular expression, you can find the index of '(' and ')' and calculate if the content is empty.